Marlin 2.1.2.2 Ender 3 Pro CR touch does not work properly
I do have an Ender-3-Pro with the Sprite Extruder Pro on it. Also, I swapped out the controller board for a BigTreeTech SKR 1.4 Turbo, which works perfectly for me. I am using the CR Touch to level the bed. After a month of trying to fix the issue with the bed leveling, I still cannot get it to work correctly.
What have I done so far:

I checked that in the firmware the mesh bed leveling is enabled and is still present after homing.
I also tried to adjust the corners based on the G29 command and looked at the visual graph that was produced from the test points.
I also tried manually adjusting the mesh bed leveling by editing the saved values. At first, it worked, but eventually, this also failed me.

I am really confused about this behavior, which is why I also tried to replace the CR Touch, in case mine was faulty, but this was not the case. I observed the same behavior in the second one.
For completeness, these are my Configuration.h values that are enabled for the CR touch:
#define USE_PROBE_FOR_Z_HOMING
#define BLTOUCH
#define AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR

Am I missing some options? Or is the CR touch not as good as the competitive alternatives, like the BL touch?
To make it clear, I observed that it wants to compensate for the right sight of the bed more than on all other ones.
Have a look here (I visualized it with 3D Printer Auto Bed Leveling Mesh Visualizer):
      0      1      2      3      4
0 -0.632 -0.694 -0.752 -0.792 -1.239
1 -0.489 -0.577 -0.667 -0.747 -1.249
2 -0.397 -0.502 -0.607 -0.707 -1.217
3 -0.227 -0.384 -0.519 -0.639 -1.174
4 -0.002 -0.194 -0.389 -0.564 -1.122

Another problem is that after one print, I can adjust the z-offset again to about 0.1 to 0.8 mm.

I've had bad luck with all my clones, I've read the CR touch is supposed to be very good nowadays.

I am not using any clone and so far I cannot tell if it is good or not. Since the problem persists I assume it has to be something with the software.

Have you rechecked the wiring? I had a problem with my CR Touch and it was loose wiring. Also, what is the observed behavior? You mention that it "does not work properly" but do not explain what is happening.

Yeah i checked the wiring and it is fine. Sorry for that I edited my post, you should now see what I mean, I also took a mesh for visualization.

You are using an economical printer with design flaws. One of the problems with this portal printer is the poor roller design in combination with the single driven Z threaded rod.
If you look closely to you bed using a bed visualizer you will see that the problem is probably not with the CR Touch, but most probably an issue with the roller system on the Z posts:

This is a common problem, please fix the gantry first and relevel again.

I upgraded now to a dual z axis and used the E1 connection for the second stepper motor. However, the problem is less present now, but after auto align the x axis the right side is still too low. After G34 and bed leveling did not solve the problem. I am currently out  of ideas what the problem may be. I also disassembled the whole printer and reassembled it again with caution. The z rods are vertical without any bends in it...
